# Javascript and html connection

Tags: javascript, html

Why is the edge of the input rectangle not colored green or red?
Probably the problem is in the JS file. How can i fix it?

This is the part of html.

```
<form action="Registrazione" method="post" name="registrazione" id="form">
<div class="signlog">
<h1>Registrazione</h1>
<p>Compila il form per creare un account.</p>   
<label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" name="username" onchange="controlloUsername()" id="uno"></form>
```

This is the part of JS.

```
function controlloUsername()
{
var lettere=/^[a-z0-9A-Z]+$/;
var username=document.forms["registrazione"].elements["username"].value;
if(username.length<5 || username.length>10 || !username.match(lettere))
{
    document.registrazione.username.style.borderColor="red";
    return false;
}
else{
    document.registrazione.username.style.borderColor="green";
    return true;
}
}

function validazione()
{
      if(!controlloUsername())
{
    document.registrazione.username.focus();
    return false;
}  
}

function registrati()
{


$.post("registrazione",
{

         username : $("#uno").val(),

     },
```

Comment: Works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/kzc8xb53/ note since you use onchange the function wont be called as you type. It is only fired after the focus has changed, eg clicking out of the input. If you want it to run as you type you should use oninput

Comment: I edited your code however you are missing some closing elements such as </div> in your form, also when you do inspect element do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I have edited with another function

Comment: @PatrickEvans in this site  jsfiddle.net/kzc8xb53 work but in my project i don't know why don't work but it's the same

Comment: @vincenzopallini provide a [mcve] but more than likely if yours does not work your function probably is not in global scope which it needs to be in order for js attributes like onchange to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JavaScript` and `HTML` are good, that's a `CSS` task. You only need to change the `input#uno`'s `border-style` property to `solid`.

```js
function controlloUsername() {
  var lettere=/^[a-z0-9A-Z]+$/;
  var username=document.forms["registrazione"].elements["username"].value;
  if(username.length<5 || username.length>10 || !username.match(lettere)) {
  
  document.registrazione.username.style.borderColor="red";
    return false;
  } else {
  
  document.registrazione.username.style.borderColor="green";
    return true;
  }
}

function validazione() {
  if(!controlloUsername()) {
  
  document.registrazione.username.focus();
    return false;
  }  
}
```

```css
input#uno {
  border-style:solid;
}
```

```html
<form action="Registrazione" method="post" name="registrazione" id="form">
<div class="signlog">
<h1>Registrazione</h1>
<p>Compila il form per creare un account.</p>   
<label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" name="username" onchange="controlloUsername()" id="uno"></div></form>
```

Hope I pushed you further.